# Find an object from array of object using an arrray element and replace it

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Let say I have two array of objects.

```
var arr1= [
  {
    pid: [ '1967', '967' ],
  },
  {
    pid: [ '910', '1967', '967' ],
  },
  {
    pid: [ '967' ],
  }
]

var arr2 = [ 
{ _id: '967', name: 'test pid' }, 
{ _id: '1967', name: 'test one test' },
{ _id: '910', name: 'this is test name' }  
]
```

is there any way I can find the _id and name from array2 using the id from arr1 and replace element of arr1.pid. like below

```
arr1 = [
      {
        pid: [ { _id: '1967', name: 'test one test' }, { _id: '967', name: 'test pid' }],
      },
      {
        pid: [ { _id: '910', name: 'this is test name' }, { _id: '1967', name: 'test one test' }, { _id: '967', name: 'test pid' } ],
      },
      {
        pid: [ { _id: '967', name: 'test pid' } ],
      }
    ]
```

so far I have done as below

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
  var pids = arr1[i].pid
  for(var j = 0; j<pids.length; j++){
    var result = arr2.filter(obj => {
      return obj._id === pids[j]
    })
    console.log(result) //can not push this into arr1['pid']
  }
}
```

Comment: `filter` returns the matching element(s) in an array. You want a single item so use `find`.

Comment: Thank you @AluanHaddad. but how can i replace the object in arr1[pid] in same index.

Comment: `arr1 = arr1.map(x => ({pid: x.pid.map(id => arr2.find(obj => obj._id === id) || obj)}))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `map` it and inside that you can find the elemenet from second array:

```js
var arr1= [ { pid: [ '1967', '967' ], }, { pid: [ '910', '1967', '967' ], }, { pid: [ '967' ], }];
var arr2 = [ { _id: '967', name: 'test pid' }, { _id: '1967', name: 'test one test' },{ _id: '910', name: 'this is test name' } ];


var result = arr1.map(k=>{
  k.pid = k.pid.map(p=>arr2.find(n=>n._id==p));
  return k;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Build an object from `arr2`, so that easy access given `key`.
2. Use `map` on `arr1` and update the array.

```js
var arr1 = [
  {
    pid: ["1967", "967"],
  },
  {
    pid: ["910", "1967", "967"],
  },
  {
    pid: ["967"],
  },
];

var arr2 = [
  { _id: "967", name: "test pid" },
  { _id: "1967", name: "test one test" },
  { _id: "910", name: "this is test name" },
];

// Build an object to from array
const all = arr2.reduce(
  (acc, curr) => ((acc[curr._id] = { ...curr }), acc),
  {}
);
const res = arr1.map(({ pid }) => ({
  pid: pid.map((key) => ({ ...all[key] })),
}));

console.log(res);
```